# Class III appliance with metal chassis connection

Tags: grounding, safety, appliances, chassis, extra-low-voltage

I am designing a SELV/Class III appliance (lab/industry type, IEC 61010), supplied via two-pin isolated DC power. For mechanical reasons, the chassis has to be metallic. As a result, there are going to be exposed metal parts of the chassis. The device internally creates an isolated high voltage from the DC power supply. I.e. the high voltage is isolated both from the DC power, as well as from mains.

Now, as it is a Class III appliance, I don't *have to* earth the chassis. But on the other hand, leaving it floating with respect to the circuit feels wrong to me; it feels like asking needlessly for EMI trouble.

The circuit inside will routinely make contact to other devices via USB. This means that circuit ground could be clamped to ~PE potential via USB and connected computers, but this is not guaranteed of course.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmJL4F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Question:

Is it ok to tie the floating metal chassis to circuit ground?

That would still ensure, should any second circuit node make fault contact with the chassis, that the chassis would be still safe to touch. The circuit will stop working properly though, so the fault will be noticed.

I heard that safety testers that probe exposed metal demand either very good continuity to PE or substantial isolation from PE. With the chassis connected to PE only via USB, wouldn't it fail both tests?

Comment: I might ask to give some context, how is this any different from say an old laptop? Isolated DC supply input, exposed metal parts in chassis, older models had isolated high voltages inside for CCFL backlight and routinely connected to other equipment which may be earthed or not.

Comment: @Justme It is probably not different the way you put it. Laptops though are probably another IEC, being consumer electronics items. The laptop chargers I have tested, often have a rather low resistance (like 1 kohm) between PE and negative DC. So I was not sure how laptops were treated. I will put up a block diagram shortly, to make it clearer.

Comment: @tobalt, Do you have the EN 61010-1 standard? Mine dates from 2010 but I think chapters 6.4 and 6.5 are worth reading. I'm not sure if you can connect the floating metal chassis to the circuit ground because of the single fault condition (6.5). In one of our designs, we had chosen "impedance protection" (a resistor with a parallel capacitor for EMC).

Comment: @Vincent No I don't have it. R||C sounds reasonable too. It would put my EMI worries to rest while never allowing for substantial continuity to PE (although again also no substantial isolation).

Comment: If not grounded, it has to be double insulated, making your product effectively Class I.

Comment: @winny I corrected the text. My appliance is Class III powered from a Class II SELV supply.

Comment: @Vincent I actually did find the 61010-1 norm in my documents, but only partially. I checked the sections you mentioned and more and it was helpful. But I am wondering whether this norm indeed even applies to the present device as it is a Class III appliance. The norm, however, seems to exclusively discuss stuff with mains connection (i.e. Class I or II appliances). Unfortunately, the introductory sections that clarify the norm's scope are missing ;)

Comment: @tobalt, You're right, EN 61010-1 deals with mains-connected devices. With regard to safety testers that probe exposed metal, the standard states (Annex F.1): No value is specified for the test current. But I don't think you're concerned by a Class III device, since it's not earthed.

Comment: @Vincent Well my actual question here is about the fact, that my device *becomes* earth-referenced when I use the USB. I have also posted a more general question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/696319/237061) about the implications of the connection between SELV and PELV circuits.