# How to interpret this wiki quote about connections between SELV and PELV circuits?

Tags: usb, safety, extra-low-voltage

The [wiki page about SELV circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage#Separated_or_safety_extra-low_voltage_(SELV)) says:

> A SELV circuit must have [...] simple separation from other SELV
> systems, from PELV systems and from earth (ground).

Assume I have a SELV Class III device with a galvanic communication interface, such as USB. Now when I connect this interface to another PELV device (e.g. computer), then I violate the simple separation requirement to PELV mentioned above and my SELV device obtains an Earth-reference.

So, my device would no longer qualify as SELV. At the same time, it has no good PE connection either, so it would also not qualify as PELV.

1. Does this (e.g. USB) connection then render my device a FELV device? Or still PELV/SELF?
2. If it becomes FELV, as far as I am aware, it would no longer qualify as Class III either, so what appliance class does it become? What measures would be necessary to make it safe?

Comment: [Discussion about workarounds in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150637/discussion-between-tobalt-and-justme). Focus the comments here on the actual question.